# Azure portal - delete database server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Over the last few weeks I have created a couple of databases and sometimes new servers using both the old and the new Azure Portals.

I have now deleted all the databases that I don't need.

How can I delete the servers that are now empty?

Comment: If you're asking how to do it through the portal, it's better to ask at ServerFault, since this isn't a programming question. If you're attempting to do it through cli/powershell, then you can rework your question to reflect this, and show where you're struggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete a server there are a couple of options. 
One simple way is to use the [Remove-AzureSQLDatabaseServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/remove-azuresqldatabaseserver) PowerShell cmdlet.

The following is an example:
`Remove-AzureSQLDatabaseServer -ServerName 'MY SERVER NAME'`
Just replace 'MY SERVER NAME' with the name of the server you want to delete.

If you haven't downloaded Azure PowerShell, you can find it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546728.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have used Azure PowerShell and it is now deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating only one DB server, then using that one server to create DB's for test/dev work. You can't create a DB server with name, when you create a DB server, the name is pretty random.

The following PS shows how to get the name of your DB Servers:

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer
```

Once you hit the max # of DB servers created (I think it's 8), you won't be able to create anymore DB's.

To delete on the portal, select DB's, then select the server tab.

Comment: You have not used the newer portal for sure. The newest one let you set the name of your server.

Comment: I never use the portal to create DB's (or anything else), I do it all from PS.